# I want to read a big text file

Tags: java

I want to read a big text file, what i decided to create four threads and read 25% of file by each one.
and then join them.

but its not more impressive.
can any one tell me can i use concurrent programming for the same.
as my file structure have some data as 
name contact compnay policyname policynumber uniqueno

and I want to put all data in hashmap at last.

thanks

Answer (score 9):

Reading a large file is typically limited by I/O performance, not by CPU time. You can't speed up the reading by dividing into multiple threads (it will rather decrease performance, since it's still the same file, on the same drive). You can use concurrent programming to process the data, but that can only improve performance *after* reading the file.

You may, however, have some luck by dedicating one single thread to reading the file, and delegate the actual processing from this thread to worker threads, whenever a data unit has been read.

Comment: if  devide the file in chunk and read it by different thread, and get the data in concurrent collection. is this increase performance

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're still talking about reading the file from more than one thread? If so, this won't improve performance. Let one thread read the file and pass a chunk to a free worker thread (use a job queue, or something similar). This way you can use all the processing power for data processing. On the other hand, you may want to use a profiler to find out where the bottlenecks actually are.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a big file chances are that it is written to disk as a contiguous part and "streaming" the data would be faster than parallel reads as this would start moving the heads back and forth. To know what is fastest you need intimate knowledge of your target production environment, because on high end storage the data will likely be distributed over  multiple disks and parallel reads might be faster.

Best approach is i think is to read it with large chunks into memory. Making it available as a ByteArrayInputStream to do the parsing.

Quite likely you will peg the CPU during parsing and handling of the data. Maybe parallel map-reduce could help here spread the load over all cores.

Comment: "If it is a big file chances are that it is written to disk as a contiguous part" - do you mean chances are it's *not* contiguous?

Comment: I mean it probably is contiguous. Fragmentation of the disk, striping, can influence that. In most circumstances disksystems are optimised for fast sequential reads.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Memory-mapped file buffers (NIO) instead of plain java.io.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might flush the disk cache and put a high contention on the synchronization of the hashmap if you do it like that. I would suggest that you simply make sure that you have buffered the stream properly (possibly with a large buffer size). Use the `BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)` constructor to specify buffer size.

If the bottle neck is not parsing the lines (that is, the bottle neck is not the CPU usage) you should not parallelize the task in the way described.

You could also look into memory mapped files (available through the nio package), but thats probably only useful if you want to read *and write* files efficiently. A tutorial with source code is available here: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm

Answer (score 0):

well you can take help from below link

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/

OR

by using large buffer

or using this

import java.io.*;

public class line1 {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  if (args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("missing filename");
    System.exit(1);
  }
  try {
    FileInputStream fis =
        new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    BufferedInputStream bis =
        new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis =
        new DataInputStream(bis);
    int cnt = 0;
    while (dis.readLine() != null)
      cnt++;
    dis.close();
    System.out.println(cnt);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
  }
}
```

}